# PHP - setrawcookie() returns false

Tags: php, cookies, url-encoding, restful-architecture

I'm currently trying to connect with my project's RESTful API, using it's SignIn function, which returns an authorization token to use as a cookie. Most of our project is written in C#, but I'm trying to create a SignIn method in PHP and have been running into an issue.

I've managed to fetch the authorization token as a string back from the API, however everytime I try and set that string as the value of a cookie, the cookie I get back has incorrect characters in it.

For example, the cookie that is set for SignIn on our RESTful API looks like this:

```
1DEbKeyynVTbXeRJ2i5j2+UgwgmuD17VgQ
```

However the cookie I get when using setcookie() gives me...

```
1DEbKeyynVTbXeRJ2i5j2%2BUgwgmuD17VgQ
```

The "+" character is being turned into a "%2B". I've heard of using setrawcookie() as a solution to this, however my setrawcookie() returns false where setcookie() returns true.

This doesn't work:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo setrawcookie("authtoken", $result, 0, "/", "www.arbitratum.com", 1);
```

This DOES work, but gives me the %2B in place of +.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo setcookie("authtoken", $result, 0, "/", "www.arbitratum.com", 1);
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might not be working? Or how I can get the correct characters in my cookie? When I echo the $result string, the string that displays in my browser uses the correct "+" character, so I'm really confused as to what the issue is.

Comment: Question title has nothing to do with the content of the question

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are url encoded, so when send via HTTP `+` gets replaced by `%2B`, to comply with the specification every browser and backend server knows (or shuold know) how to handle that.

So the question would be how you're handling the cookie in `C#`... are you simply reading the header information from the request, then you should remember to url decode the values, this way you'll get back the string containing the `+` character.

Comment: I'm not sure how they handle the approach in C#, but the cookie that's stored when running the SignIn method on our API is NOT url encoded, and so far any attempt at authorization that I've made with URL encoded cookies has failed. There should be a way to generate a raw cookie with + in it in PHP, which is what I need to figure out here.

Comment: Simply using `echo setrawcookie('authtoken', '1DEbKeyynVTbXeRJ2i5j2+UgwgmuD17VgQ')` returns true for me - have you tried without using the extra parameters? Also you set up the `secure` flag, are following requests all made via HTTPS?